# concept of base, derive class and use them properly

Tags: c++, c++11

**you have to use the concept of base, derive class and use them properly. while doing it, I'm faced with some problems.
Can you help me solve the issues ?**

My Code :

```
#include <iostream>


class Base {
    public:
    Base (int data) : _data(data){}
    virtual void printData(){
        std::cout << "Base" << _data << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int _data;
};

class Derived : public Base {
    public:
    Derived(derivdata) : Base(derivdata){}
    void printData(){
        cout << "Derived " << _data << endl;
    }
}


int main(){
    Derived *var = new Derived(5);
    var-> printData();
    Base* basevar = static_cast<Base>(*var);
    basevar-> printData();
}
```

Comment: What are the issues

Comment: Don't use any casts. `Derived*` is already convertible to `Base*` implicitly: `Base* basevar = var;`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I dont get it .. can you share me right code in pastebin ?.. please ...

Comment: @Yksisarvinen OTOH 1) `*var` is not implicitly convertible to a `Base*` 2) You need a cast to create another `Base` object w/ a 1 arg ctor. 3) But a `Base` is not convertible to a `Base*`

Comment: @AdamLois Your line is 100% wrong. Do you want to create a copy of `*var`?

Comment: Also how is that a **C language** related question?!!!

Comment: @curiousguy  I dont get it .. can you share me right code in pastebin ?.. please ...

Comment: Can you describe in English what `Base* basevar = static_cast<Base>(*var);
 ` is trying to do?

Comment: @curiousguy I never said that `*var` is convertible to `Base*`. My assumption was that OP is trying to convert pointers, not to make a copy of `*var`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Indeed. My comment was intended for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

`Base* basevar = static_cast<Base>(*var);` is wrong,
it would be `Base* basevar = static_cast<Base*>(var);`
but `Base* basevar = var;` is sufficient.

and version without memory leak:

```
int main(){
    Derived derived(5);
    derived.printData(); // "Derived 5\n"
    Base& base = *derived;
    base.printData();    // "Derived 5\n" as method is virtual
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here, that could be typos:

- a missing semicolon after the class `Derived`
- in the constructor `Derived(derivdata) : Base(derivdata){}` the type of `derivdata` is missing. (there is no default int in c++)
- you are missing the namespace `std::` before `cout` and `endl` in `Derived::printData`
- in `Derived::printData` the member `_data` is not accessible, because it is private to `Base` (You could make it protected or write a getter for it)

The core problem is this cast: `Base* basevar = static_cast<Base>(*var);` This will actually dereference the value of `var`, then try to cast this value to `Base`, and afterwards tries to assign the result (of type `Base`) to a variable of type `Base*`.

For polymorphic casting you can use [dynamic_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast): `Base* basevar = dynamic_cast<Base*>(var);`

But don't expect `basevar->printData();` to print "Base", since the pointer is still pointing to an instance of `Derived` and the method is declared `virtual`.

To access a method of the base class you need to explicitly tell the compiler to do so: 
`basevar->Base::printData();`(prints "Base5")

Comment: Why would you need "polymorphic casting" for?